# Scala : Error in sorting

Tags: scala, sorting

I have a class defined as below :

```
class VocabWord(cn1: Int = 0, word1: String = null)  {
   var cn = cn1
   var word = word1         
}
```

and also there exists an array as below :

```
var vocab = new Array[VocabWord](100)
```

Now, when I perform an operation like this below :

```
vocab = vocab.sortWith((x, y) => x.cn < y.cn)
```

I am getting an null pointer exception.

Comment: **please** use CamelCase for class names.  `vocab_word` is an eyesore, the convention is to write `VocabWord`.  `_` is already too far overloaded in Scala!

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing the array with 100 `null`'s

```
var vocab = new Array[VocabWord](100) // Array(null, null, null.....)
```

You can't apply the method `cn` to `null`

```
var vocab = Array[VocabWord](new VocabWord(100), new VocabWord(3))
vocab.sortWith( (x, y) => x.cn < y.cn)
// Array(VocabWord@49ac9ae3, VocabWord@21a4c98e)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an array with new elements in, you can use `Array.init`:

```
val vocab = Array.fill[vocab_word](100)(new vocab_word)
```

at present you are creating an array containing 100 null references.